# alignment issue in media query

Tags: html, css

So am trying to align these cards I made using flexbox at a smaller screen size using media query but for some reason am having a bit of trouble aligning the items at the center of the screen when it shrinks down to match the media query am wondering why this occurs. I tried aligning them to the center but it doesnt work.

```
 <section class="bg-lightcareml container">
    <div class="container-section">
        <h2 class="prod-items">Our Products</h2>
        <div class="card-items">



            <div class="card">
                <img src="blackbird.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="card-text">
                    <h2>CyberWare</h2>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum perferendis iure asperiores
                        dicta quis vel fugiat, soluta nam laboriosam.
                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="card">
                <img src="blackbird.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="card-text">
                    <h2>CyberWare</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sint tempore doloremque vero
                        placeat officiis eaque nisi velit rerum dolorums.</p>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="card">
                <img src="blackbird.jpg" alt="">

                <div class="card-text">
                    <h2>CyberWare</h2>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis nulla numquam in
                        provident deserunt! Cumque excepturi delectus
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>

    </div>

</section>



:root {
    --clr-pr-200: #fceded;
    --clr-pr-300: #bceeff;
    --clr-pr-400: #0c0d0d;
    --clr-pr-dr-: #ded9d9;

    --clr-ctrl-100: #ffffff;
    --clr-ntrl-900: #222C2A;

    --ff-pr: 'Times New Roman', sans-serif;
}
    
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 62.2%;
    font-family: Roboto, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

}


body {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.3175rem;
    line-height: 1.6;
}

.bg-lightblue {
    background-color: var(--clr-pr-300);
    height: 12vh;



}

.container {
    margin-inline: auto;
    width: min(95%, 210rem);

}



/*card-section*/



.bg-lightcareml {
    background-color: var(--clr-pr-400);

}

.container-section {
    margin-top: 3rem;
    min-height: 820px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
    padding: 0.6rem;
}

.container-section>.prod-items {

    text-align: center;
    font-size: x-large;
    font-family: var(--ff-pr);

}

.prod-items {
    padding: 1.8rem 0 0 0;
    color: var(--clr-pr-200);
}


.card-items {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;



    gap: 2.5rem;

}

.card {
    display: flex;


    flex: 0 1 200px;

    flex-direction: column;

}

.card .card-text {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;





}

.card-text {
    background: var(--clr-ctrl-100);
    padding: 1.2rem;
    margin-top: -6px;

}

@media (max-width:35rem) {


    .container-section {
        padding: 5rem 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;









    }

    .card-items {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;





        margin-top: 1.1rem;


        max-width: 200px;





    }






}









h2,
p {
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-size: 1.666rem;
    font-weight: 500;

}

h2 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.76rem;
}

.card-items h2 {
    text-align: center;
}


.card-items p {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 930px
}

.card img {

    max-width: 300px;
    aspect-ratio: 1.3 / 1;
    width: 100%;


}
```

Comment: I advise you to write the css for smaller screens first (`@media screen and (min-width: 601px)`), so that way you can prevent things like this happening. Second, don't put rems in the media querys. The best practice is to put pixels, so you know the exact screen size.

Comment: I see thanks but am wondering why this happens

Comment: I'm not so sure because your code was all over the place and it was easier just to make the changes. Keep in mind what I told you in the previous comment and your life will be easier.

Comment: ok i tried way i showed and it work great but i also retried mind and the problems was i didnt realize the flex-direction chance to column so the main-axis is from top to bottom instead of left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Will this help? I don't know how you wanted it to look, but I think I think it has a better base you can build on.

```css
:root {
    --clr-pr-200: #fceded;
    --clr-pr-300: #bceeff;
    --clr-pr-400: #0c0d0d;
    --clr-pr-dr-: #ded9d9;

    --clr-ctrl-100: #ffffff;
    --clr-ntrl-900: #222C2A;

    --ff-pr: 'Times New Roman', sans-serif;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 62.2%;
    font-family: Roboto, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.3175rem;
    line-height: 1.6;
}

.bg-lightblue {
    background-color: var(--clr-pr-300);
    height: 12vh;
}

.container {
    margin-inline: auto;
    width: min(95%, 210rem);
}

/*card-section*/
.bg-lightcareml {
    background-color: var(--clr-pr-400);

}

.container-section {
    margin-top: 3rem;
    min-height: 820px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
    padding: 0.6rem;
}

.container-section>.prod-items {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: x-large;
    font-family: var(--ff-pr);
}

.prod-items {
    padding: 1.8rem 0 0 0;
    color: var(--clr-pr-200);
}

.card-items {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 300px;
}

.card .card-text {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.card-text {
    background: var(--clr-ctrl-100);
    padding: 1.2rem;
    margin-top: -6px;

}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    .card-items {
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .card {
        width: auto;
        margin: 0 10px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="bg-lightcareml container">
        <div class="container-section">
            <h2 class="prod-items">Our Products</h2>
            <div class="card-items">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="blackbird.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="card-text">
                        <h2>CyberWare</h2>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum perferendis iure asperiores
                            dicta quis vel fugiat, soluta nam laboriosam.
                        </p>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="card">
                    <img src="blackbird.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="card-text">
                        <h2>CyberWare</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sint tempore doloremque vero
                            placeat officiis eaque nisi velit rerum dolorums.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card">
                    <img src="blackbird.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="card-text">
                        <h2>CyberWare</h2>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis nulla numquam in
                            provident deserunt! Cumque excepturi delectus
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make 2 changes when on mobile

@media (max-width: 35rem)

```
.container-section {   
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

and it would be ok

Comment: yea but I want it to align to the center at smaller screens

Comment: that's what will happen

Comment: https://codepen.io/theorios/pen/bGvRQzN